# Need help in reaching content to scrape website behind cloudflare

Tags: web-scraping

I am trying to scrape articles from the following website: https://dzkuensel.com using Python.
However, if I use, e.g. `requests.get()` (or even `selenium`), I don't reach the contents I need because of this:
[image]
[image]
Can anyone suggest a workaround?

Comment: Use cloudscraper.

Comment: Thanks, I tried but it doesn’t seem to do anything…

Comment: I get ```cloudscraper.exceptions.CloudflareChallengeError: Detected a Cloudflare version 2 Captcha challenge, This feature is not available in the opensource (free) version.```

Comment: I seem to be able to bypass that by setting ```disableCloudflareV1=True``` but then the response I get is 403 and I am back to exactly the content I get with `requests`

Answer (score 0):

Setting some cookies and headers seem to solve the problem for me...

```
import requests

cookies = {
    'cf_clearance': 'GpVnDnCl9tkRWCpGeyXaDZRCkyj9ah0oq8bVcJPUd9E-1664729507-0-150',
}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'DNT': '1',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'cross-site',
    'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
}

response = requests.get('https://dzkuensel.com/', cookies=cookies, headers=headers)
```

```
response.text
'<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang="en-US" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">\n<head>\n<meta charset="UTF-8" />\n<link rel="profile" href="https://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />\n<link rel="pingback" href="https://dzkuensel.com/xmlrpc.php" />\n<title>ཀུན་གསལ། &#8211; རྒྱལ་ཡོངས་ཉིན་བསྟར་གསར་ཤོག།</title>\n<meta property="og:title" content="ཀུན་གསལ། - རྒྱལ་ཡོངས་ཉིན་བསྟར་གསར་ཤོག།"/>\r\n<meta property="og:type" content="website"/>\r\n<meta property="og:description" content=""/>\r\n<meta property="og:url" content="https://dzkuensel.com/"/>\r\n<meta property="og:site_name" content="ཀུན་གསལ། - རྒྱལ་ཡོངས་ཉིན་བསྟར་གསར་ཤོག།"/>\r\n<meta name=\'robots\' content=\'max-image-preview:large\' />\n<link rel=\'dns-prefetch\' href=\'//fonts.googleapis.com\' />\n<link rel=\'dns-prefetch\' href=\'//s.w.org\' />\n<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="ཀུན་གསལ། - རྒྱལ་ཡོངས་ཉིན་བསྟར་གསར་ཤོག། &raquo; Feed" href="https://dzkuensel.com/feed/" />\n<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="ཀུན་གསལ། - རྒྱལ་ཡོངས་ཉིན་བསྟར་གསར་ཤོག། &raquo; Comments Feed" href="https://dzkuensel.com/comments/feed/" />\n\t\t<script type="text/javascript">\n\t\t\twindow._wpemojiSettings = {"baseUrl":"https:\\/\\/s.w.org\\/images\\/core\\/emoji\\/13.1.0\\/72x72\\/","ext":".png","svgUrl":"https:\\/\\/s.w.org\\/images\\/core\\/emoji\\/13.1.0\\/svg\\/","svgExt":".svg","source":{"concatemoji":"https:\\/\\/dzkuensel.com\\/wp-includes\\/js\\/wp-emoji-release.min.js"}};\n\t\t\t!function(e,a,t){var n,r,o,i=a.createElement("canvas"),p=i.getContext&&i.getContext("2d");function s(e,t){var a=String.fromCharCode;p.clearRect(0,0,i.width,i.height),p.fillText(a.apply(this,e),0,0);e=i.toDataURL();return p.clearRect(0,0,i.width,i.height),p.fillText(a.apply(this,t),0,0),e===i.toDataURL()}function c(e){var t=a.createElement("script");t.src=e,t.defer=t.type="text/javascript",a.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(t)}for(o=Array("flag","emoji"),t.supports={everything:!0,everythingExceptFlag:!0},r=0;r<o.length;r++)t.supports[o[r]]=function(e){if(!p||!p.fillText)return!1;switch(p.textBaseline="top",p.font="600 32px Arial",e){case"flag":return s([127987,65039,8205,9895,65039],[127987,65039,8203,9895,65039])?!1:!s([55356,56826,55356,56819],[55356,56826,8203,55356,56819])&&!s([55356,57332,56128,56423,56128,56418,56128,56421,56128,56430,56128,56423,56128,56447],[55356,57332,8203,56128,56423,8203,56128,56418,8203,56128,56421,8203,56128,56430,8203,56128,56423,8203,56128,56447]);case"emoji":return!s([10084,65039,8205,55357,56613],[10084,65039,8203,55357,56613])}return!1}(o[r]),t.supports.everything=t.supports.everything&&t.supports[o[r]],"flag"!==o[r]&&(t.supports.everythingExceptFlag=t.supports.everythingExceptFlag&&t.supports[o[r]]);t.supports.everythingExceptFlag=t.supports.everythingExceptFlag&&!t.supports.flag,t.DOMReady=!1,t.readyCallback=function(){t.DOMReady=!0},t.supports.everything||(n=function(){t.readyCallback()},a.addEventListener?(a.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",n,!1),e.addEventListener("load",n,!1)):(e.attachEvent("onload",n),a.attachEvent("onreadystatechange",function(){"complete"===a.readyState&&t.readyCallback()})),(n=t.source||{}).concatemoji?c(n.concatemoji):n.wpemoji&&n.twemoji&&(c(n.twemoji),c(n.wpemoji)))}(window,document,window._wpemojiSettings);\n\t\t</script>\n\t\t<style type="text/css">\nimg.wp-smiley,\nimg.emoji {\n\tdisplay: inline !important;\n\tborder: none !important;\n\tbox-shadow: none !important;\n\theight: 1em !important;\n\twidth: 1em !important;\n\tmargin: 0 .07em !important;\n\tvertical-align: -0.1em !important;\n\tbackground: none !important;\n\tpadding: 0 !important;\n}\n</style>\n\t<link rel=\'stylesheet\' id=\'lafs_style-css\'  href=\'https://dzkuensel.com/wp-content/plugins/follow-subscribe/css/lafs_style.css?lafs_version=1.1\' type=\'text/css\' media=\'all\' />\n<link rel=\'stylesheet\' id=\'tie-insta-style-css\'  href=\'https://dzkuensel.com/wp-content/plugins/instanow/assets/style.css\' type=\'text/css\' media=\'all\' />\n<link rel=\'stylesheet\' id=\'categoryposttab-css\'  href=\'https://dzkuensel.com/wp-content/plugins/category-and-post-tab/assets/css/categoryposttab.css\' type=\'text/css\' media=\'all\' />\n<link rel=\'stylesheet\' id=\'wp-block-library-css\'  href=\'https://dzkuensel.com/wp-includes/css/dist/block-library/style.min.css\' type=\'text/css\' media=\'all\' />\n<link rel=\'stylesheet\' id=\'bwg_frontend-css\'  href=\'https://dzkuensel.com/wp-content/plugins/photo-gallery/css/bwg_frontend.css\' type=\'text/css\'
```

Comment: Thanks @Rivered I am not sure why but I copy pasted and still get a response like before (i.e. this ` <div id="challenge-body-text" class="core-msg spacer">
            dzkuensel.com needs to review the security of your connection before proceeding.
        </div>`

Comment: Load this website in your browser, copy the curl from the network request in inspector tools, convert the curl to python with a webtool, and try again :)!

Comment: Same problem as before.

Comment: It is strange though you can't even load the page in Selenium. Are you trying headless?

Comment: Mmm not sure I did try headless (as you may have guessed I am not a super expert)